# php sending variables to the page after the next page

Tags: php, html

well my question is pretty simple and easy but just want some confirmation to know if i get it correctly or that there is another option.

I want some variables from page1 to be send to page3 after the steps @page2 are completed.
Do i need to get all the variables too page2 in the
    '
    
    '
and so on
, and then post it again too page 3. or is there a way to skip that because it looks nasty in my opinion.

Comment: Session variables? Databases? Cookies? There are all kinds of ways.

Comment: As @lonesomeday said, there are any number of ways you could accomplish this.  It really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

First page:

```
<?php
 session_start(); 
 $_SESSION['data'] = 'boo';
?>
```

Next Page:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['data'];
?>
```